# Find duplicate objects that already exist in database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database table with objects. The objects have a PK and a unique index with 4 properties. What I want to do is add the new object to the db, and move the duplicate "old" object from to another table a.k.a "History".

So when I upload a new csv file I want to get all the existing objects in the db that are duplicates of objects in the new csv file.

The csv files can be big and have more than 10k objects, so it takes a long time to loop through them and check if the index/id exists in the database.

I tried to save the objects with an unique index key, but do not know how to get the already existing object(s).

Screenshots for reference:

[Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMxWi.png)

[Parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2nFg.png)

Comment: Do you care about performance? Or just need that via pure EF?

Comment: I do care about performance. I use ef since that is the only thing I know.

Comment: Well, I'll prepare sample with third party EF Core Extension. Which database do you use?

Comment: Azure Sql Server

Comment: Also add your entity class. It will be easiest to show what to do.

Comment: Update question with class, not comment.

Comment: What with you guys? I need class, not an images. And description why there are two classes. If there two classes, it means that you read two CSV files

Comment: I dont quite understand with you mean class? We read a CSV file that has session of charges. But the object can overlap between CSV files. So I need too remove all object that exist in the db and add the new ones. Old ones goes to history table,

Comment: Well, I have created answer, but I need to correct that using new information.

Answer (score 0):

Since EF Core do not supports bulk operations for performance reason it is better to do that with third party extension (disclaimer I'm one of the creators) https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore

For fast reading CSV, I suggest this library https://github.com/mgholam/fastCSV
It will load file continuously via IEnumerable without using a lot of memory.

Better to implement such inserting with temporary table:

```cs
var items = ... // you have read CSV file and created enumeration of objects, let's name them SomeItem
using var db = ctx.CreateLinqToDBConnection();
using var temp = db.CreateTempTable("#to_inject", items);

var queryToHistory = 
   from s in db.GetTable<SomeItem>()
   from t in temp.InnerJoin(t => t.key1 == s.Key1 && t.Key2 == s.Key2 && t.Key3 == s.Key3)
   select s;

using var tran = db.BeginTransaction();

// inserting into History table
queryToHistory.Insert(db.GetTable<SomeItemHistory>(), s => new SomeItemHistory 
  {
     Key1 = s.Key1,
     Key2 = s.Key2,
     Key3 = s.Key3,
     
     Value1 = s.Value1,
     Value2 = s.Value2,
     ...
  });

// inserting new records or update existing
db.GetTable<SomeItem>()
  .Merge()
  .Using(temp)
  .OnTargetKey()
  .InsertWhenNotMatched()
  .UpdateWhenMatched()
  .Merge();

tran.Commit();
```

Comment: This worked good! But when creating "CreateTempTable". It says that the Id must be a numeric number. Is there a way too change this?

Comment: Well, which entity? Which type of `Id` in database?

Comment: Better update you question with classes and DDL for the tables.